# Stripe "trial_end" not working in subscription using php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a subscription using stripe API. But it won't save once I included the `"trial_end" => 1602762687`

I have attached my code.

```
// Include Stripe PHP library
    require_once 'stripe-php/init.php';
    
    // Set API key
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_API_KEY);
    
    // Add customer to stripe
    try { 
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'source'  => $token
        ));
    }catch(Exception $e) { 
        $api_error = $e->getMessage(); 
    }
    
    if(empty($api_error) && $customer){ 
    
        // Convert price to cents
        $priceCents = round($planPrice*100);
    
        // Create a plan
        try {
            $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
                "product" => [
                    "name" => $planName
                ],
                "amount" => $priceCents,
                "currency" => $currency,
                "interval" => $planInterval,
                "interval_count" => 1
            ));
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            $api_error = $e->getMessage();
        }
        
        if(empty($api_error) && $plan){
            // Creates a new subscription
            try {
                $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
                    "customer" => $customer->id,
                    "trial_end" => 1602762687,
                    "items" => array(
                        array(
                            "plan" => $plan->id,
                        ),
                    ),
                ));
            }catch(Exception $e) {
                $api_error = $e->getMessage();
            }
```

It does work when I remove trial_end, but when i add the trial time it generates an error for some reason.

Please help thanks.

Comment: Which version of Stripe API are you using?

Comment: `"items" => array(array( "plan" => $plan->id, ),` Does not look like something that exists at that position in the [Stripe API Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create).

Comment: it's actually 2020-05-11

Comment: What is the error that is generated?

Comment: Have you set `billing_cycle_anchor`?

Comment: In your catch blocks try `error_log(print_r($e,true));` to help you debug

Comment: You can also look in your dashboard developer logs to see what errors were returned by your API request:
https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs

Comment: Before anyone can help you we'll need to see what the error is.

Comment: @Martin The logs file doesn't show any error,

Comment: @NolanH No error in the log

Comment: You say in your question `it generates an error for some reason.` but you're now saying that no error is generated? Please **edit** your question and clear this confusion. If no error is infact generated, then what is your actual problem?

Comment: Yea your question says "generates an error for some reason": why do you say there's an error?

Comment: it's because I am getting an error in my application `Subscription activation failed!,` but the stripe log file is showing everything Ok, seems like I have done something wrong in the PHP library.